# Angular router.navigate with relativeTo keeps redirecting me back to home page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use relative routing to navigate back to a parent route, but I keep getting redirected back to my home page. I can route successfully with things like:

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/account/account-settings')
```

or by using an anchor tag in my html template

```html
<a href="/account/account-settings">working link</a>
```

But when I try to use `this.router.navigate`, I get errors:

```js
// Examples:
this.router.navigate(['/account/account-settings']) // redirects to home page
this.router.navigate([''], {relativeTo: this.route}) // When in /account/account-settings/target. This redirects to home page.
```

But these work fine if I'm navigating from `/account/account-settings` to `/account/account-settings/target`, or to any other URL `/account/account-settings/<anything>`. I just can't route from `/account/account-settings/<anything>` back to `/account/account-settings`

I've set up enable tracing with:

```js
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }),
```

And I get an error as so: `Navigation ID 15 is not equal to the current navigation id 16', code: 1, type: 2}`:

```
Router Event: NavigationCancel
NavigationCancel(id: 15, url: '/account/account-settings')
NavigationCancel {id: 15, url: '/account/account-settings', reason: 'Navigation ID 15 is not equal to the current navigation id 16', code: 1, type: 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like my problem was that I had 2 separate navigation events being triggered. I had a `(click)` event triggering my navigate call, ie:

```js
this.router.navigate(['/account/account-settings'])
```

But I also had `routerLink="./"` on the same html element, so I was effectively navigating twice.

One thing I don't yet understand is why it worked for "./" routes, but not the "./" route?

Comment: Mine had an href in the link. This helped me a lot with debugging.